# I can't append struct object to array object in golang (GIN Framework)?

Tags: mongodb, go

I can't append struct object to array object in golang (GIN Framework)

```
func (dish *DishesController) RetrieveMultipleDishesItemsByCategoryId(c *gin.Context) {
    //TODO 1 :Bind Json from request body
    //          2: Call function for read document in mongodb by categoryId
    //          3. Response data, finish

    var categoryFromRequest DishesModel.CategoryFromRequest
    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&categoryFromRequest); err != nil {
        c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"message": err.Error()})
        return
    }
    for _, items := range categoryFromRequest.Category{
        // loop call function for get dishes info

        data, err := newService.FindDishesByID(items.Id)
        if err != nil {
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"message": err.Error()})
            return
        }

        categoryFromRequest.Category = append(categoryFromRequest.Category, data)

    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aR8xA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KW1D.png)

Comment: Be more pedantic: share the struct/type, explain what you wish to return, right now looks like you to try append a entry to the current request, not the response

Answer (score 0):

Slice/Array in Go must have all its elements be the same data type. Since categoryFromRequest.Category (type of []struct{...}) and data (type of DishesModel.DishesDataModel) are not the same types, you cannot append it to an array.